# no css/javascript when anonymous

Tags: 7, javascript, theming

I finally was able to fix my site in our stage environment until I logged out of the admin section. Now the site has no css at all. All the html seem to be fine. If I login as admin, the site is still perfect.

I tried to clear cache, still same problem...

I tried to change the theme, the new theme has css. As soon as I get back to the original theme: no css as anonymous.

I looked at the source code and the includes are not there at all. So forget about a bad path.

I looked at my theme.info and it is fine.

What can possibly add  tags in the  while logged in as admin and not as anonymous?

Note: when there is no css, there is no javascript. So you could read this question and replace all "css" for "javascript"

Comment: If the problem's only there with one theme, the problem has to be in the code for that theme...not necessarily the .info file, there are plenty of things a theme could do to break css/js with hooks

Comment: to test, start renaming tpl files one by one (page.tpl.php to page_2.tpl.php or something like that), including theme settings, and template.php - when it works, you will at least know which file is causing the problem and you can go from there.

Comment: I think I pin pointed my problem. Fortunately, I had the same problem in local. It seems the hook_js_alter from my base theme is conflicting with the hook_js_alter's theme. The js_alter from the base theme is taking precedence and I don't know why. I thought that the base theme's template.php would not be read. I fact it is read first and it's a big problem for me.